# Remote-Container on one server working, on other doesn't work

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

So I have a remove server that runs a container.
I manage to connect to it through VsCode and the Remote Docker extension by changing the `docker.host` property to `"ssh://username@server"` and then going to the Remote Explorer section and seeing all my containers there.

Now I want to connect to another remote container in another server. So I changed the property described above to fit the new server, but there are no containers showing in Remote Explorer. changing back to the old server works normally.

I am sure the addresses are correct (as I can connect to it) and that password less ssh is set up in the new server as well.

What am I doing wrong? there might be a step that I did when I set up the old server back in the day that I'm forgetting I need to do now.

Edit: Checked on a third server and it works normally, what could be the problem with the second server? If it helps, its a nvidia DGX machine.

Comment: The docker daemon is up on that second server? Is there any container running on it?

Comment: @VonC yea, my container is running on it

Comment: Maybe the remote SSH user is not the right one? Or said remote user is not part of the docker group on the remote server?

Comment: I can connect manually to both the server using SSH and to the container using the same user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to look if the docker version are compatible

Comment: I just checked and the DGX server has docker 18.X and the other ones have 19.X
I'll try to upgrade the docker version of the DGX to see if this was the problem.

Comment: That was the problem!